# Get All Public Facebook Events by Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

Over here need to ask whether there is any workaround to get all facebook events even if it is of a particular city.

I have also tried by getting venus and then getting events happening over there, but it is strictly inefficient.

API to get events using lat lng
search?q=*&type=event&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000

But in the response to the above query I found they are for sure not events in any way.

Also there is FQL
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/
This FQL functionality which is now not supported by Facebook, did it used to work earlier and get all the events from facebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can only get events by name, the location parameters are for places only: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search